# How to send large json data through intent in android

Tags: java, android

I already know how to send data between Activities using Intent, the problem is, my server request returns a `ArrayList` of Images in string base64, and I notice that a large string crashes the app, there's any other way to do this? This how I usually do :

1 Activity :

```
String passing_data = new Gson().toJson(user);
Intent intent = new Intent(activity,UserAdsView.class);
intent.putExtra("passed_data",passing_data);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

2 Activity :

```
String target = getIntent().getStringExtra("passed_data");
UserModelView userModelView = new Gson().fromJson(target,UserModelView.class);
```

It doesn't show any error in Console or something, it just crash, and reopen the the previously activity. Thanks!

Comment: Save image to file system and pass file name in intent?

Comment: In my case, this is a "Temporary" image, in the first Activity it shows a CardView with a few information and a Image, when I click at the item, starts a new Activity with those additional informations including the "stringsImagesArray", but I can't make it thought!

Comment: You can request again to server in the second activity instead of passing the value from first activity.

Comment: Even if it is temporary you can save it on disk and delete it after you don't need it anymore

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. What do you mean? are you trying to pass a JSON Object or are you trying to pass an arraylist?

I'm guessing you are in need of a bundle and a  serializer. Try something like this.

```
    // Create your new Intent
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity,UserAdsView.class);
    //create a bundle
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    //when you add a list of objects (JSON or Otherwise), use a serializer
    b.putSerializable("passed_data", passing_data);

    intent.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(intent);
```

then in your new activity you need something like this:

```
    ArrayList<String> target = (ArrayList<String>) b.getSerializable("passed_data");
```

Comment: The array list is a property.its not separated